# Is my manuscript too big for my computer to handle?

Tags: google-drive, google-docs, google, document-management

I'm an author working from an **HP Probook 440 G5.** I've been writing in **Google Docs** for about a year, and I'm almost done with my first book's second draft, which I hope to show to a professional publisher and editor before I graduate from high school in a couple of years. It's reached **about 220 pages**, and I'm really proud of it. The problem is, **Chrome keeps crashing when I open it to the point where there have been weeks where I couldn't even type anything before getting that "Aw, snap!" ERROR_CODE_HUNG message**. I'm really distressed because I don't have any other reasonable way of accessing this project. *Is there anything I could do to make my writing any easier?* Thank you for the help!

Answer (score -1):

How much memory (RAM) do you have? How full is the hard drive? Check both of those first. There could be a simple solution.
Adding more RAM is the easiest. https://www.memoryx.com/hp.html has the least expensive RAM. Your model is about 3/4 or more towards the bottom. They sell more RAM than anybody and ship or mail to you. You go through their lists to find your computer model. It will show the maximum RAM allowed, the number of memory slots, and the various sizes of the memory sticks that are available for your computer.
Switching to a bigger hard drive is a little more difficult because you would first have to clone the internal hard drive to a bigger hard drive hooked up externally. There are cheap ($20 or so) kits to hook up a drive via USB. After cloning to the external drive you would then have to open up the computer and exchange the drives. An easier alternative is to just have the external USB drive as an additional drive. It would show up on the desktop as a second drive. You could move enough of the files (including your project) to the external drive to free up space. Then the computer would run OK.

By the way, an easy and reliable way to clone the drive is to use G4L as a boot CD. It is more dependable than Clonezilla. I have never had a problem with it unlike Clonezilla. You download it from here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/g4l/files/g4l%20ISO%20images/, burn it to a blank CD using XfBurn or another similar program, then boot your computer from the CD you created. G4L is self-explanatory. Just make sure you copy in the right direction or you could wipe out all the data on the internal drive.
If your problem is due to the word processing software running remotely on Chrome, somebody else has to answer that. I am not familiar with Chromebooks so I don't know if that is the case.

To find out your current RAM layout, download SystemRescueCD or similar program from here:  https://www.system-rescue-cd.org/ and burn it to a blank CD, bot from it and run the memory testing program. That will give you the layout as well as tell you if the memory is good (which could be the problem).